# Different Partial Derivatives Used in Curl in Proof of Stokes' Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was reading [this proof](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/4.-triple-integrals-and-surface-integrals-in-3-space/part-c-line-integrals-and-stokes-theorem/session-92-proof-of-stokes-theorem/MIT18_02SC_MNotes_v13.3.pdf) of Stokes' theorem, which uses two different forms of partial derivatives in its syntax. The function at hand is $P(x, y, f(x, y))$, describing an arbitrary surface in 3-space.

The former partial derivative is that without applying a partial derivative to the third term of $P$. It is notated by $P_n$, where $n$ is the nth argument of $P$. The latter partial derivative applies the partial derivative to the third term of $P$ according to the chain rule. It is notated with $\partial/\partial{k}$ for each variable. For example, it is clear that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}P(x, y, f) = P_1(x, y, f) + P_3(x, y, f) \cdot f_x$$

by the chain rule. Oddly enough, when calculating $\nabla \times (P \cdot \vec k)$ in the proof, the former partial derivative is used! In calculating curl, shouldn't the latter partial derivative be used to account for the effects of $f$'s reliance on $x$ and/or $y$? How does one determine here which partial derivative to use? The equation referenced is on page 2 of the above link.

Comment: The answer is that you must pay attention to the context in which those calculations are given. It's all about the relations between $x,y$ and $z$ which depend on the context. It's not right to think about this just in terms of partial derivatives. The story is much more about the surface or boundary around which we are forming the surface or line integral.

Comment: Thank you @JamesS.Cook! That clarified things for me.

Comment: Glad to help, for what it's worth, you can also take a look at pages 390-392 of my notes where I go through the usual argument for Stokes' Theorem on a graph with a nice domain; http://www.supermath.info/CalculusIIIf2014.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the primary issue involved is that the functional nature of the surface at hand is irrelevant - therefore, noting how the variables change with respect to one another is counterproductive. @JamesS.Cook stated it best in his comment which explained it to me:

> The answer is that you must pay attention to the context in which those calculations are given. It's all about the relations between x,y and z which depend on the context. It's not right to think about this just in terms of partial derivatives. The story is much more about the surface or boundary around which we are forming the surface or line integral.